# Nuxt - un-nest page from nuxt-child

Tags: nuxt.js

I have the following structure

```
categories/_tag/_post
```

Which, in Nuxt, looks like this at the moment:

```
/categories.vue
/categories/_tag.vue
/categories/index.vue            (blank file which shows when the /categories page loads)
/categories/_tag/_post.vue
```

`categories` has a `nuxt-child` component in it, so the `_tag` page loads within it.

**The problem I have is that the `_post` page is loading inside the `categories` `nuxt-child` as well, rather than on its own page.**

I'd like the views to load like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use named-views.

Examples can be found here
https://nuxtjs.org/examples/named-views/

The key here is in the nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  router: {
    extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
      const indexIndex = routes.findIndex(route => route.name === 'index')
      let index = routes[indexIndex].children.findIndex(route => route.name === 'index-child-id')
      routes[indexIndex].children[index] = {
        ...routes[indexIndex].children[index],
        components: {
          default: routes[indexIndex].children[index].component,
          left: resolve(__dirname, 'components/childLeft.vue')
        },
        chunkNames: {
          left: 'components/childLeft'
        }
      }

      index = routes.findIndex(route => route.name === 'main')
      routes[index] = {
        ...routes[index],
        components: {
          default: routes[index].component,
          top: resolve(__dirname, 'components/mainTop.vue')
        },
        chunkNames: {
          top: 'components/mainTop'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
``
```